# $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x)$ for $f_n(j/n) = 1/(n + 1)$, for $n \geq 1$ and $j = 0, 1, \ldots , n$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm kind of confused about this exercise. Let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of density function and $\{F_n\}$ their correspondent distribution function. Suppose that $f_n(j/n) = 1/(n + 1)$, for $n \geq 1$ and $j = 0, 1, \ldots , n$, $f_n(x) = 0$ in other case. Find, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x)$. For example for $n = 1$, we have $f_1(0)=1/2$ and $f_1(1)=1/2$. For $n = 2$, we have $f_2(0)=1/3$ and $f_2(1/2)=1/3$ and $f_3(1)=1/3$. My guess is when $n \to \infty$ then $F_n(x)=0$ but I do not know if this is correct.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $F_n(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_n(y)dy$

Comment: Yes, but I kind of confused about $f_n(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question implies that $f_n$ is actually a sequence of mass functions (as opposed to density functions). If we take it to be density functions, then this would be $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ for $x \in [0, n]$, which does not integrate to 1. Therefore, we define
\begin{align*}
F_n(x) = \int_{(-\infty, x]} f_n(x) d\mu(x)
\end{align*}
where $\mu(x)$ is the counting measure. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
F_n(x) = \int_{[0, x]} f_n(x) d\mu(x) = \frac{\lfloor xn+1\rfloor}{n+1} \in \left[\frac{xn}{n+1}, \frac{xn+1}{n+1}\right]
\end{align*}
Therefore by the squeeze theorem,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} F_n(x) = x \quad \text{for } x \in [0, 1]
\end{align*}

Comment: I see, I did long time ago a similar exercise. It states that if  $X_n \sim U(0, 1, . . . , n)$ and $X \sim U[0, 1]$, prove that $1/nX_n \xrightarrow{D} X$. Thanks!